# RegEx with quotes not matching anything in Java

Tags: java, regex

I can have one of the following sample strings:

```
Apple $Banana Kiwi

Apple $Banana, Kiwi

Apple $Banana. Kiwi
```

I need to find litterally "$Banana"

In java 6, I have used this:

```
String quotedStringToFind=Pattern.quote(stringTofind);
```

I also need to find the full word, so i tried with this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b"+quotedStringToFind+"\\b");
```

Nothing is matched. RegEx is syntactically correct. I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need to know if the input has "$Banana" in it, or do you want to extract the middle word?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm going off of the assumption that OP knows the word is `$Banana`, since the variable is named `stringTofind`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Definition of word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

> [...] It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Given

> `Apple $Banana Kiwi`

the first scenario fails since `$` is not a word character. So there can be no match before the first character in the string.

Based on your comments elsewhere, you don't want to match strings like `"$Bananayellow"`, so we can assume you want the literal `"$Banana"` terminated by something other than word characters.

As Tim suggests in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531502/regex-with-quotes-not-matching-anything-in-java/26531580#comment108829570_26531799), you can use the regular expression `(?<!\S)\$Banana\b`. The expression will check that `$Banana` is not preceded by a non-whitespace character and that it's followed by a word boundary.

For example,

```
List<String> testStrings = List.of("Apple $Banana Kiwi",
                                   "Apple $Banana, Kiwi",
                                   "Apple $Banana. Kiwi",
                                   "Apple $Bananayellow. Kiwi");

// need to escape the special `$` character
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)\\$Banana\\b");

for (String testString : testStrings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("failed to find pattern in string " + testString);
    }
}
```

This will only print the last string containing `"$Bananayellow"` since that doesn't match the `Pattern` used.

Comment: @Sotirios The regex lesson continues: `(?<!\S)` not only asserts whitespace preceding, but also the start of the string.  Ideally, you'd like your pattern to also match `$Banana` when it happens to be first.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

- `$` is a reserved character meaning "end of the string". You will need to first escape any reserved character (`\^$.|?*+()[{`), or compile the expression with `Pattern.LITERAL` like in @Reiumeus's answer.
- There is no word boundary between the space and the `$` in `Apple $Banana`, since they are both non-word characters. Assuming you want there to be a space before or after the `stringTofind`, you can use an expression like this: [`(?<=\\s|^)\\$Banana(?=\\s|$)`](http://regex101.com/r/nV9lJ7/1) (note that this won't work with `Pattern.LITERAL`, since it wouldn't evaulate the lookarounds).